# Forward Postfix mail based on regexp

Tags: email, postfix

We are buildng a ticket system using PHP. We have now bumped into the problem of identifying customer replies.

- Placing an id in the subject will not do because users could remove this.
- Posting an id in a custom header will not do because certain mail clients will remove this.
- Posting a code in the mail body will not do either because just as with the subject, users can remove this.

We thought of placing the id in the email address. `t<ticketid>@mydomain.com`

However, we are not sure how to redirect this to `support@mydomain.com`

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to use `+` style sub-addresses: `support+<ticketid>@mydomain.example`.  Postfix will deliver those mails as if they were send to `support@mydomain.example`, ignoring the sub-address.

Postfix also allows to define a different character to be used.  Set the `recipient_delimiter` parameter in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to the desired values:

```
recipient_delimiter = +-
```

This would allow both `support-ticketid@mydomain.example` and `support+ticketid@mydomain.example`, handling both addresses in the same way.

Some Linux distributions ship postfix with `recipient_delimiter` set to `+`, so this might already work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the virtual_alias_maps [*]:

```
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases
```

and fill /etc/postfix/aliases with

```
/t(.*)@mydomain.com/ support@mydomain.com
/t(.*)@mydomain.com/ support+${1}@mydomain.com
/^(.*)@domain1.com$/ ${1}@domain2.com
```

then run command and update virtual.db

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

you can of course fine-tune the regex to exactly match your ticketid code (ie. only numbers etc.) or use backreferences.

[*] if you don't use any virtual domains in postfix you can also use alias_maps, but how it works can sometimes be confusing, read https://serverfault.com/questions/644306/confused-about-alias-maps-and-virtual-alias-maps about it

Comment: can't edit (max 6 char changes ) but please add /^t on being when its start wit letter